# how to programmatically unswipe the swipe to delte cell in SwipeCellKit library?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]i am using [SwipeCellKit](https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit) library to perform swipe to delete method in collection view. i have completed what i want till now. But i am also doing another thing is that , in this there is a multiselection in collection view. so when i do multiselect and one of the cell is in swiped state so that cell hides that delete functionality.
[image]

Comment: You should check `editActionsForItemAt` delegate method, you can add condition there if you want to pass any action or not.

Comment: action is adding but the image is after  i changed the state of cell to selected. in this delete button hides.

Comment: Please add your code to understand better.